# how to integrate / link R and Computer Algebra Systems (CAS)

Tags: math, r, statistics, maxima

I'm looking for a possibility to use different 'higher' math operations in combination with [R](http://www.r-project.org/). A link or integration between R and a CAS would be the perfect solution.

Which integration of R and other (math & statistic related) systems or vice verse are out there? How well do they work? What would you suggest? How expansive (in time, money and frustration) are they?

(FOSS is of course preferred :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you looked at the [Ryacas](http://cran.r-project.org/package=Ryacas) package which brings Yacas to R?

The [SAGE](http://www.sagemath.org) project has a focus on CAS and offers an R integration.

Comment: Ryacas & yacas is totally new to me and seems promising.
I tried SAGE shortly - it felt big and a bit messy...

Comment: Yes, Sage is too large for my personal taste too.

Comment: reading about Yacas I also found the fork mathpiper and the R package rmahtpiper (linkes on the page of Ryacas). This combination seems to be very easy overall :)

Answer (score 4):

There is also [rsympy](http://code.google.com/p/rsympy/) ([CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rSymPy/index.html)):

rSymPy is an R package giving R users access to the SymPy computer algebra system running on Jython from within R.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly there is only a link to matlab and not maxima...